# setup and deployment of project

Tags: c#, setup-project, exe

I have developed Speech to text application and want to create setup file.

I have British voice and American voice executable file that must be installed on the computer where my project is installed because my application uses this voice.

So,how can i attach these two files with my project setup file so that when user install my project,setup asks for installation of these two files also..?

Comment: (After seeing you comment below) So one or both of the executables should run during installation of your product to install themselves? If so, do you know if these modules are installed by Windows Installer?

Answer (score 0):

What I have often seen done is to install both exe's (I'm assuming the .exe's aren't too huge), then prompt the user the first time he runs. Save the users choice and only launch that exe from now on.

If the config file is deleted, you will just ask again.

Comment: but how user will install exe?manually..?i want that while iinstallation of project,these two exe run automatically (user may be asked and warned if he says not to install) and then my project gets iinstalled.

Comment: With this solution, there would be nothing you would need to do during installation besides copying both exe's and other data into the installation directory. There will be a script that runs when you launch to check the config file for which version to run.

Comment: hello...

i solved my above problem using custom action option that is available while creating setup and deployment project.                                                    now,these two exe  run automatically when installation of my project is continue.

but what i want is

   1) if currently any of these 2 products are already  installed on user's machine,then skip this Item
   2) display dialogbox  asking weather to install these  products or not (and warn if he says no) 

please anyone help me with regarding ideas.

thank you friends.